# Access query criteria from check box in from

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-forms

Please help me to solve the below query criteria based on a checkbox in the form.

```
IIf([Forms]![TYPEBRANDLOCATION-MAINFORM]![CHKAGE4plus]= True,>=4,>=0)
```

The result returns only the value with 0.

Please help to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this expression:

```
>=IIf([Forms]![TYPEBRANDLOCATION-MAINFORM]![CHKAGE4plus],4,0)
```

Comment: Hi, Gustav,   \this works fine thanks, thanks for all supported

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to modify the `where` clause in your SQL code the something along the lines of the following:

```
where
[YourField] >= 0 and
([Forms]![TYPEBRANDLOCATION-MAINFORM]![CHKAGE4plus]=False or [YourField] >= 4)
```

Changing `[YourField]` to the applicable field name to which the selection criteria applies.